# What's the 2-adic analogue of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$ factoring through the quotient $PSL(2,\Bbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm investigating $SL_2$ over some superset of the products of positive dyadic and ternary rationals $\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+$.

For my application it is useful to have the 2-adic value on hand.  To this end the superset I am currently using as a setting is the field $\Bbb Q_2$ , although this is not set in stone.  And what is more, it is useful for me to have the 3-adic value on hand, so to this end I am restricting myself to the periodic elements of $\Bbb Q_2$ insofar as is possible.

In order to understand $SL(2,\Bbb Q_2)$ I have the statement for $\Bbb R$:

The group action factors through the quotient $PSL(2, \Bbb R)$ (the 2 × 2 projective special linear group over $\Bbb R$).

**Question**

What's the 2-adic analogue of this statement - is it any different, and what does it mean?

**Background**

I don't think this affects the answer that much but it explains the motivation and that may allow a more helpful answer:  The function of the well-known Collatz conjecture can be seen as acting on the quotient $\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+/\langle2,3\rangle$, which you can think of as having one 5-rough number as a representative of every element - which you arrive at by dividing out the powers of two and three.

We get a rather elegant representation of the Collatz conjecture within the special linear group over the 2-adic field $SL_2(\Bbb Q_2)$ using the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&&2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1}\\0&&1\end{pmatrix}$.  This is an epimorphism on $\Bbb Q_2$ (assuming some means of assigning powers of $3$ to the aperiodic elements).

This matrix is just one "choice" of infinitely many possible representations of the Collatz function which respects the rays of the quotient $/\langle2,3\rangle$, but it is the one which sits within $SL_2(\Bbb Q_2)$ and it also happens to be the one for which the level sets of the function accumulate to their image, so it seems to have the better claim to be the "chosen" representative.  I'd like to understand more about this and the implications of it factoring through the quotient $PSL(2,\Bbb Q_2)$, if that is indeed the 2-adic equivalent of the statement for $\Bbb R$.

Comment: you should perhaps write which action you mean (I didn't find it in your question)

Comment: It's true for any finite-dimensional vector space over any field that the action of $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ on $V$ induces an action on the projectivisation $P(V)$ ("the set of lines through $0$"), and the kernel of this action is the set $Z$ of unit-determinant scalar multiples of the identity, so the action factors through the quotient $\mathrm{SL}(V)/Z = \mathrm{PSL}(V)$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @user8268 I took it from the third sentence here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R) .  It says that the group acts on the complex upper half plane so I guess that is material to my question although I hadn't clicked when writing the question that it is the action **on a set** and the choice of set is material.  I guess that raises the question; *what takes the place of the **complex upper half plane** in the case of $\Bbb Q_2$.*

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen yes, I think that's half of what I'm asking. I'm asking whether that's the case, and also what the statement means. For me, I have come to find that the general case (as you have given) is less illumnating than the specific example until I am familiar with a few specific examples. E.g. what is the $P(V)$ in my case, the kernel, and what does it mean for an action to factor through a quotient?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen as an example of what's ambiguous, I know what a scalar is in $\Bbb R$, but in $\Bbb Q_2$ the only scalar is $2^n$ so is the set of lines through $0$, the set $P(\Bbb Q_2)=\{\{x\cdot2^n:n\in\Bbb Z\cup\{0\}\}:x\in\Bbb Z_2^\times\}$ or does multiplying by a unit still count as scaling in this setting?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure what you mean by the only scalar being $2^n$. In this case $V$ is the 2D vector space $\Bbb Q_2\times\Bbb Q_2$, and $P(V)$ is the set of sets of the form $\Bbb Q_2 v$ for $0 \ne v \in V$ (ie the one-dimensional $\Bbb Q_2$-vector subspaces). In general if $K$ is a field then the group $\mathrm{PGL}_2(K)$ can be thought of as rational transformations acting on $K \cup \{\infty\}$, which is related to this. See eg [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group#Fractional_linear_transformations). Getting to grips with the Möbius group may help build some intuition!

Comment: As for what a kernel is and what it means for an action to factor through a quotient - an action of $G$ on $X$ is a homomorphism $\phi: G \to \mathrm{Sym}(X)$, and this action factoring through a homomorphism $\theta: G \to H$ (in this case, the quotient map) means that there's a homomorphism $\psi: H \to \mathrm{Sym}(X)$ such that $\phi = \psi \circ \theta$. In other words, an action of $H$ on $X$ such that $g \ast_G x = \theta(g) \ast_H x$ for all $x \in X$ and all $g \in G$. So it means here that in the quotient, you still have all the "information" about the way the group acts on $P(V)$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen by only $2^n$ being a scalar, I mean if you multiply any ball in $\Bbb Q^2$ by a unit it remains unchanged in size - only the $2^n$ component scales it. But I see from your comment scalar here doesn't really have anything to do with topological size. Thanks for your helpful comments.